# Can PathPatternParser/PathPatern be used in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

PathPatternParser and PathPattern ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html)) ([jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14544)) seem to have more functionality than 
AntPathMatcher ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)).
But looks like they are not enabled in spring mvc by default. According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) they can be used in web reactive.

I specially want to use following wildcard matching in spring mvc:

> {*spring} matches zero or more path segments until the end of the path and captures it as a variable named "spring"

This functionality is similar to as described [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14032)

My question:

Can PathPatternParser/PathPattern be used instead of AntPathMatcher in Spring MVC?